# What is the difference between .element( and .$( with protractor?

Tags: protractor

Can someone explain to me the difference between these two ways of clicking with protractor:

```
element(by.repeater('calc in calculations').row(0)).$('#copyCalc').click()
or

element(by.repeater('calc in calculations').row(0)).element(by.css('#copyCalc')).click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quote from protrator docs for $:

'Shortcut for querying the document directly with css'

[source for $](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementfinderprototype)

As far as i understand, $('.aCssClass') and element(by.css('.aCssClass')) are the same.

[source for element](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementfinderprototypeelement)